# "npm install node-session" on termux app. Then i got this error. How can i install node-session on termux?

Tags: android, node.js, npm

```
npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm WARN deprecated @mapbox/geojsonhint@2.0.1: Please make plans to check GeoJSON in some other way
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../@mapbox/geojsonhint/bin/geojsonhint
npm ERR! dest /storage/emulated/0/Coding/noda/node_modules/.bin/geojsonhint
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../@mapbox/geojsonhint/bin/geojsonhint' -> '/storage/emulated/0/Coding/noda/node_modules/.bin/geojsonhint'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../@mapbox/geojsonhint/bin/geojsonhint' -> '/storage/emulated/0/Coding/noda/node_modules/.bin/geojsonhint'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../@mapbox/geojsonhint/bin/geojsonhint',
npm ERR!   dest: '/storage/emulated/0/Coding/noda/node_modules/.bin/geojsonhint'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2022-04-25T18_23_32_395Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Install it with `--no-bin-links`.